# UDP - correct way for closing connection

Tags: networking, udp, communication

I have a client server programs which communicate with UDP protocol. I am using UDP because it is much faster than TCP but sometimes I need the know for sure if the packet reached to the other side, In my program I can not use TCP at all so I am sending ack packets. It work fine for sending data.

The problem is when I am trying to close communication between the client and the server. I have designed it so the client will send a message to the server that it wants to close the communication. In this case it is very difficult to send ack for the message because of the situation when the oher side is no longer there.

For an instance, the client want to close the communication, so it send the server a message for it, the server gets it and send an ack for the client, then it closes the communication. The ack supposed to reach the client but in a case that the ack didn't the client will try to resend the close communication message but the server is no longer there.

So what is the best way to close communication in UDP?

Comment: Same as TCP. Just treat the FIN as another piece of data to be sent, acknowledged, resent if not acknowledged, and eventually timed out.

Comment: So when should i close the client or server?

Comment: When you've finished with it?